# How to read information from SSL certificate file

Tags: java

I'm newbie to SSL certificate, i need to read validation date and expiration date from a local .crt file not a URL as shown in the following print screen:

[image]

So is there a JAVA Api that helps to do it.

Comment: @notyou thank you for your help but i need to read it from a local .crt file not form a direct URL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the certificate to and from dates like so:

```
CertificateFactory fac = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("\\path\\to\\file\\cert.crt");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) fac.generateCertificate(is);
System.out.println("From: " + cert.getNotBefore());
System.out.println("Until: " + cert.getNotAfter());
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can create a certificate from an input stream using a  [CertificateFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html)

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(fis);
```

Then you can query information from the specific certificate type, eg [X509Certificate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html).